# How to construct an interface over types which contain different signatures, but with params all corresponding to the same type

Tags: c#

I have several car factories:

HondaFactory, MercedesFactory, ToyotaFactory

All of these factories have a `Create()` method:

```
Honda Create(HondaParts parts);
Mercedes Create(MercedesParts parts);
Toyota Create(ToyotaParts parts);
```

All return types implement `ICar`, and all parts implement `ICarParts`.

I have a class above all this which, when given a factory type and an `ICarParts`, wants to simply call `Create()` on the factory without an if/else/if/else statement on the type.

I went to create an `ICarFactory` and give it an interface of:

```
ICar Create(ICarParts parts)
```

But then I got stuck, as of course each factory has a different signature, even though all of the parameters comply with the ICarParts type. Is there any way to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use generics

```cs
abstract class CarFactory<TParts> where TParts : ICarParts 
{
    public abstract ICar Create(TParts parts);
}

class HondaFactory : CarFactory<HondaParts>
{
    public override ICar Create(HondaParts parts)
    {
        ...
    }
}

... other factories
```

But as always with generics there are limits. E.g., you cannot create a List<Factory<?>> containing different types of factories. The different types of factories are not assignment compatible.

At some point you will still need the if/else/if/else statement to get the right factory. The non-generic, weakly typed approach `ICar Create(ICarParts parts)` allows more "dynamic" scenarios.

Since C# 9.0 (and .NET 5.0 runtime, I think) you can use [covariant return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns) :

```cs
    public override Honda Create(HondaParts parts)
    {
        ...
    }
```

assuming `public class Honda : ICar`.

---

A more sophisticated approach combines a non-generic and a generic interface. Program against the non-generic interface in more dynamic but weakly typed scenarios and against the generic one in other cases:

```cs
public interface ICarFactory
{
    ICar Create(ICarParts parts);
}

public interface ICarFactory<in TParts> : ICarFactory
    where TParts : ICarParts
{
    ICar Create(TParts parts);
}

abstract class CarFactory<TParts> : ICarFactory<TParts>
    where TParts : ICarParts
{
    ICar ICarFactory.Create(ICarParts parts) => Create((TParts)parts);

    public abstract ICar Create(TParts parts);
}
```

Note that the non-generic implementation is done explicitly and is therefore only visible when programming directly against the `ICarFactory` interface. Now, you can, e.g., create a factory dictionary like this:

```cs
var factories = new Dictionary<string, ICarFactory> {
    ["Honda"] = new HondaFactory(),
    ["Mercedes"] = new MercedesFactory(),
    ["Toyota"] = new ToyotaFactory(),
};
```

It is now your responsibility to provide the right type of parts:

```cs
string carType = "Toyota";
ICarFactory factory = factories[carType];
ICar car = factory.Create(parts); // Not type safe!
```